# Letter Grid 5x5 number 1

Tags: word, anagram

In this grid there are five mixed-up words, shuffled only vertically. Can you find them all?

> ```
> suvet
> wtetl
> hport
> soaee
> dhuse
> ```

For example, if the words were egg, sky and pie, we might see:

> ```
> eke
> sig
> pgy
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is this (I found it without seeing the other answer first).

> sport
>  state
>  duvet
>  house
>  wheel

It is fairly easy to match the second column letters correctly to the first column letters, as there are

> only two vowels which must match with the d and h, and then the only possibility for the w is wh. So you have wh, sp, st, and either du/ho or do/hu.
>  The v is the only consonant in the third column, and so one of do/hu or du/ho must be followed by the v, the other by a vowel. This means you must have huv or duv, and duvet is as far as I can tell the only possibility. The rest then follows fairly easily.

Answer (score 6):

I think I've found one answer

> whorl 
>  duvet 
>  speet 
>  state 
>  house

Provided you accept

> [speet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speet), meaning 'to stab'.

Comment: I don't really use obsolete words, but you are close.